# Passing a prop from a Screen back to App in React Native

Tags: react-native, navigation

I'm trying to make a basic app which uses React Navigation to search films and display a list. In my 'Main' Screen it displays an InputText box where I type in a film and in another Screen it displays the results using the omdb API.

My problem is how do I pass information from my Main Screen --> App --> Api

ALl I can think of is it would be like the opposite of screenProps but I cant see how it would be implemented.

This is some pseudocode to show what I'm thinking.

```
Main Screen
<TextInput onChangeText = {set App State}

App
state = {
 what was passed by Main Screen
}
<App NAvigator screenProps = {whats the APi returns after its sent the state} />

Api
Takes whats in the App State and returns the film array

Movie Details
Takes the film array passed as a screenProp in App and turns it into a list of films.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would pass another prop that is a callback function. Not sure what your code looks like, but an example would be:

In your main screen:

```
// on the click of the search button

fetch("myserver.com/search", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({
        search: this.state.inputText
    })
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(apiResults => {
    this.navigate("MovieList", { 
            list: apiResults,
            onMovieSelected: (selectedMovie) => {
                 console.log("User selected a movie "+selectedMovie.title);
            }
        }
    }
)
```

In your movie list:

```
// after a user chooses a movie
props.navigation.state.params.onMovieSelected(selectedMovie)
```

Comment: Your code would work for passing the Api results from the Main Screen to the Movie List but how would I obtain these api results? That is, how would I take the input I have from the Main Screen and send it to my App.js file where the Api fetches the keyword I decide to pass.

Comment: That depends entirely on what kind of server you have.. I've updated my example to demonstrate what you'd do if you had a simple HTTP server that would respond to a POST.